# K8s: How to enable metric collecting for Redis (Prometheus)

Tags: kubernetes, redis, prometheus, bitnami

I installed from helm prometheus stack (prometheus-community/kube-prometheus-stack).

After that I updated my redis helm config, I enabled monitoring:

values.yaml:

```
...
metrics:
  enabled: true
  ...
  serviceMonitor:
    enabled: true
    namespace: "monitoring"
  ...
```

I see that servicemonitor was created and redis has 3 sidecar containers:

- metrics
- redis
- sentinel

But I don`t see redis metrics in Prometheus :(

Should I add something else?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Below troubleshooting steps will help you to resolve your issue:

1.Check if your deployments are in running state without any errors.

2.Check if the service exporter is working fine and pointing to correct pods

```
 kubectl describe servicemonitors <redis-exporter-servicemonitor> -n <service-monitor-namespace>
```

3.Check if the correct namespace selector is used.

4.As per this [git issue](https://github.com/prometheus-community/helm-charts/issues/1769) label monitoring: prometheus should be added in `kube-state-metric`.

```
kube-state-metrics:
  prometheus:
    monitor:
      enabled: true
      additionalLabels:
        monitoring: prometheus
```

5.If you are still facing issues check logs for errors and go through this [troubleshooting doc](https://github.com/prometheus-operator/prometheus-operator/blob/main/Documentation/troubleshooting.md#has-my-servicemonitor-been-picked-up-by-prometheus).

Additionally you can also check the [blog](https://logz.io/blog/how-to-monitor-redis-with-prometheus/) on monitoring redis using prometheus written by Gapilan Sivasithamparam and another [blog](https://sysdig.com/blog/redis-prometheus/) authored by David.

Comment: Label helped me, after I added to redis: `additionalLabels.release: prometheus-stack` - it started work.